# Canvas with Children as a Style

Tags: silverlight

Sorry if this is a dense question, but I'm looking to see if there is a way to have a style resource of `Canvas` in App.xaml and also have children on that Canvas and just refer to it in the `Style` of another canvas. The resource I envision would be something like:

```
<Style x:Key="Background1" TargetType="Canvas">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="500"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="600" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Children">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Rectangle Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="20"  Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Yellow"></Rectangle>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And then calling it would be as simple as:

```
<Canvas Style="{StaticResource Background1}"  x:Name="CanvasRoot"  >
    <Rectangle x:Name="PageRectangle" Canvas.Left="114" Canvas.Top="84" Height="378" Width="210" Stroke="#92D050" Fill="#C0504D" />
</Canvas>
```

Any  thoughts on if something like this can be done. What I've done doesn't work because there is no "Children" property on Canvas.

Comment: It might be better if you described why you want to do this?  There are several approaches to delivering a pre-populated control, UserControl, custom templated control, attached properties.  However determining the best advice is difficult without specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to add a child to a Canvas via a Style? I'm afraid this is simply not possible. Styles allows you to set the values of an elements dependency properties, such as Height, Background, Stroke etc ... You can also use them to set attached properties. However, the Children property you are trying to set is not a dependency property, it is the collection of children elements that describe the children of your canvas in the visual tree.

The only way to add new elements t the visual tree using styles is to add them to some controls template. Unfortunately you canot template panels (Canvas, Grid, StackPanel). You could use a ContentControl and add your rectangle as part of its template.

A ContentControl is a lookless container of a single child. See the template described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334411%28VS.95%29.aspx

Here it is, templates to add a rectangle. I am not sure what layout you are trying to achieve, but it should give you the general idea

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="myContentControl">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                  <Canvas>
                    <Rectangle Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="20"  Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Yellow"></Rectangle>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                  </Canvas>
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
```

```
<ContentControl Style={StaticResource myContentControl}>
  <Canvas x:Name="CanvasRoot"  >
    <Rectangle x:Name="PageRectangle" Canvas.Left="114" Canvas.Top="84" Height="378" Width="210" Stroke="#92D050" Fill="#C0504D" />
  </Canvas>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: +1 This is a good answer,  its a good run down on why pre-populating a Canvas via a style is difficult.  Not sure about the offered solution but thats because we don't really know what OP is actually trying to acheive.